# Python: socket.error: [Error55] Connection reset by peer

Tags: python, python-2.7, xnat

I am trying to access XNAT server via PyXNAT. While doing so i get the following error which i think is an SSL error..

Central=Interface(server='http://hd-hni-xnat.cac.cornell.edu:8443/xnat')
User: sdb99
Password:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyxnat/core/interfaces.py", line 228, in __init__
    self._get_entry_point()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyxnat/core/interfaces.py", line 268, in _get_entry_point
    raise e
socket.error: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
```

Is there any work around to solve this problem ..?

Many Thanks in advance!!

Suyash

Answer (score 0):

Can you try accessing the URL from the server where you're running XNAT using curl? Something simple like:

```
curl -u sdb99:passwd -sL -w "%{http_code}\\n" "http://hd-hni-xnat.cac.cornell.edu:8443/xnat/data/projects" -o /dev/null
```

This should tell you the exact error code or condition and make it easier to figure out what's going wrong where.